# Distance between point and polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, distance, great-circle

### Task

Calculate the distance *d* in meters between a query-point *q* and a polygon *P*.

The query-point *q* is defined as tuple (latitude<sub>*q*</sub>, longitude<sub>*q*</sub>), the polygon *P* as ordered list of tuples [(latitude<sub>1</sub>, longitude<sub>1</sub>), ..., (latitude<sub>*n*</sub>, longitude<sub>*n*</sub>)].

### Problem

I can't handle latitude and longitude as if they were *x*- and *y*-coordinates of a plane as this leads to huge errors if the polygon is not small and not near (0, 0).

### Tools

I know how to calculate the distance between two points given each points latitude and longitude. I do also know how to calculate the distance between a point and a great circle. But for this task I'd need to know how to calculate the distance dist(*q*, 1—2) between a point *q* and and part of a great-circle 1—2. The distance of *q* would be simply min(dist(*q*, *a*—*b*)) ∀ *a*—*b* in *P*.

### Question

Can you provide me a formula how to calculate the distance between a query-point *q* defined by a tuple (latitude<sub>*q*</sub>, longitude<sub>*q*</sub>) and a great-circle-arc defined by pair of latitude-longitude-tuples [(latitude<sub>1</sub>, longitude<sub>1</sub>),(latitude<sub>2</sub>, longitude<sub>2</sub>)]?

### Example

[image: Query-point *q* and polygon *P* defined by eight points). What is the distance *d* in meters?]

Comment: Can you post your formula for distance between two points in latitude / longitude? There are several ways you might express it / normalize it, so it would help who answers the question to see how you are thinking about it

Comment: I believe what you search is the so called **cross track distance**, meaning the distance of point q to the nearest point of a great circle a--b path, [This page from movable type](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) may be of interest for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you had code to compute the distance between one point *x* and a geodesic line
segment *s*, you could repeat this for each edge of your geodesic polygon.

Let *s*=(*a*,*b*). *s* is an arc of a great circle. Rotate the sphere so that
*s* lies on the equator, and *x* follows along with the sphere rotation.
Then the latitude of *x* essentially tells you the distance to *s*: It is either
the distance from *x* to *a*, or *x* to *b*, or, if *x* lies in the sector above/below *s*, it is a simple factor (2 π r) times the latitude.